# Leverage browser caching aws s3 and cloud front

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Google page speed is complaining about my browser cache, but at the same time its also showing me that the resources do seem to have an expires time (60 mins & 2 hours).

.

This is what the google pagespeed shows me.

[image]

And what I'm seeing in my s3 bucket.

[image]

[Page Speed Link](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Frussellperkins.net%2F)

Answer (score 0):

Page Speed may be suggesting that the expiry/ max-age is too short.

Consider increasing it, or better yet, use [URL fingerprinting](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#invalidating-and-updating-cached-responses) and set the max-age to *forever* (ex. 1 year).